# Flex File I/O Error #2038 - file.upload fails on Mobile IOS

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, file-upload, flex3, flex4.5

I need to upload an xml file to the server with a IOS application developed in Flex. I am getting a
Flex File I/O Error #2038. It is a very generic i/o error and doesn't provide any further details that would help me track down the root problem. Everything goes well on Windows when debugging the App it only happens when I debug the App on the apple Air tablet.

I ran into this post https://www.catalysts.cc/en/wissenswertes/flex-file-io-error-2038-on-mac-clients/ which looks like something similar but to be honest I wasn't able to use this information. It seems that my tablet may be corrupting the URL. I haven't made any traffic monitoring but I can swear the call is not even made.

Here is the code:

```
 var f:File = new File('app-storage:/Output_WithAllInfo.xml');
 var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
 request.url = http://myHost/JsonServer/?country=DE&language=deu&operationtype=custom&select=[{\"item\":\"*\"}]&sessionid="+sessionId+"&custom=[{\"package\":\"eu.app\",\"name\":\"syncInUpload\",\"data\":{\"nxpkeyProcessId\":"+processId+",\"nxpkeyProcessDefinitionId\":null,\"xml\":null}}]";
 request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
 f.upload(request,"xml", false);
```

The request parameters are:

```
authenticate:true
cacheResponse:true
 contentType:null
data:null
digest:null
followRedirects:true
idleTimeout:0
manageCookies:true
method:"POST"
requestHeaders:[] length:0
url:http://domain/JsonServer/?country=DE&language=deu&operationtype=custom&select=[{"item":"*"}]&sessionid=b9f33c5e-0445-49d3-ab5c-a335229596cf&custom=[{"package":"eu.app","name":"syncInUpload","data":{"nxpkeyProcessId":606,"nxpkeyProcessDefinitionId":null,"xml":null}}]
useCache:true
userAgent:"Mozilla/5.0 (iOS; U; de) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/3.7"
```

And I get the error:

```
 Error #2038: File I/O Error. URL: http://domain/JsonServer/?country=DE&language=deu&operationtype=custom&select=[{"item":"*"}]&sessionid=b9f33c5e-0445-49d3-ab5c-a335229596cf&custom=[{"package":"eu.app","name":"syncInUpload","data":{"nxpkeyProcessId":606,"nxpkeyProcessDefinitionId":null,"xml":null}}]
```

I really need help here...
Thanks

Should I try something like this:

```
 var req:URLRequest=new URLRequest("url");
req.method=URLRequestMethod.POST;
var postData:URLVariables=new URLVariables();
postData.country= 'DE';
postData.language='deu';
postData.operationtype= 'custom';select='[{\"item\":\"*\"}]';
sessionid=e.session;
custom='[{\"package\":\‌​"eu.app\",\"name\":\"syncInUpload\",\"data\":\"nxpkeyProcessId\":606,\"nxpkeyProc‌essDefinitionId\":null,\"xml\":null}}];
req.data = postData;
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.dataFormat=URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
loader.addEventListener‌​(Event.COMPLETE,
loader_complete);
loader.load(req);
```

Comment: Can you open the file and put the XML into a `TextArea`?  Also look into using `File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("Output_WithAllInfo.xml");` to open your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem was encoding the URL I changed the code to:

```
var f:File = new File('app-storage:/Output_WithAllInfo.xml');
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest();
var jsonParams:String = "/JsonServer/?country="+e.country+"&language="+e.lang+"&operationtype=custom&select=[{\"item\":\"*\"}]&sessionid="+e.sessionId+"&custom=[{\"package\":\"eu.app\",\"name\":\"syncInUpload\",\"data\":{\"nxpkeyProcessId\":"+e.processId+",\"nxpkeyProcessDefinitionId\":null,\"xml\":null}}]";
request.url = GlobalCGStaticVars.ipAddressJsonCalls+htmlencodeSpecial(jsonParams);
request.url = 'http://myHost'+htmlencodeSpecial(jsonParams);
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
f.upload(request,"xml", false);


protected function htmlencodeSpecial(str:String):String
    {
        var result:String = '';
        for (var i:int=0 ; i< str.length; i++)
        {
            var unicode:String = '';

            if(str.charAt(i)=='{')
                unicode = '%7B';
            else if(str.charAt(i)=='[')
                unicode = '%5B';
            else if(str.charAt(i)==':')
                unicode = '%3A';
            else if(str.charAt(i)==']')
                unicode = '%5D';
            else if(str.charAt(i)=='}')
                unicode = '%7D';
            else if(str.charAt(i)=='"')
                unicode = '%22';
            else 
                unicode =  str.charAt(i);


            result += unicode;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the UrlVariables class  [Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Comment: @Dave yes, put in postData all the requiered parameters you mentioned,this way the escaping is done by the runtime and you should not wory about encoding of parameters causing issues. Make an edit of your question and add code you tried ,don't put code in comment, just mention you updated the question

Comment: The xml file I am uploading is very big it has 10 encoded images in it. The guys from the backend said if I send that as byteArray it is too long.

Comment: @Dave send a small file and see if that works, I am not sure if you assignt he custom object to the postData, I think I can't help more, maybe try amking custom an object or Array not a string and let UrlVariables to do the work of encoding it. If you have access on the server side code maybe you can find out the exact error